# I am getting page not found on my hybris newly created b2b website using hybris cms cockpit

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, b2b

I have newly created a b2b accelerator website and included catalog, catalog version, category and products, personalization etc. when I am trying to live edit staged version adding home page into it then it is redirecting me to login prompt and if I login then the page not found message showing. I am new at hybris. I don't know what could be reason of prompting login while attempting to live edit. Even using smartedit editing also has the same manner.

I would be very grateful if anybody can help me regrading this issue. I didn't find any tutorial how to customize b2b accelerator website making configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When you see a generic hybris "page not found message" the url you called will most probably not be registered in your storefront. When you open your cms site in hmc/backoffice there is an attribute called "URL pattern". This attribute holds a list of strings, which are regular expressions. Every request you fire against the storefront has to match at least one of those regular expressions. That way, you can have more than one site on one hybris server.

E.g. there are the sites electronics, apparel, powertools, all available on the same machine but using different urls: http://electronics.local:9001/, http://apparel.local:9001/ and so on.